# force inner elements to overflow-x

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have structure of :

```
#navBar {
    height: 55px;
    width: 40px; 
    overflow-x:scroll; 
    overflow-y:hidden;
}

<div id="navBar">
akdhbaIDBhbfbhwhfbaibf
    <div style="width: 80; float: left;  text-align: center;">
    <img src="http://192.168.2.105/SB_Site/icons/Home2.jpg" alt="Nav1" />
    <br />
    <span style="font-size: 80%">Nav1</span>
    </div>
    <div style=" width: 80; float: left;  text-align: center;">
    <img src="http://192.168.2.105/SB_Site/icons/Home2.jpg" alt="Nav2" />
    <br />
    <span style="font-size: 80%">Nav2</span>
    </div>
    <div style=" width: 80; float: left;  text-align: center;">
    <img src="http://192.168.2.105/SB_Site/icons/Home2.jpg" alt="Nav3" />
    <br />
    <span style="font-size: 80%">Nav3</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want that all of the inner `div`s will `scroll-x` and *not* break the line. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Hi,I need all the inner divs will be in one line.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This will work:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #navBar {
        height: 55px;
        width: 80px;
        overflow-x: scroll;
        overflow-y:hidden;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }

    #navBar div {
        display: inline-block;
    }
</style>
```

and for HTML part:

```
<div id="navBar">
        akdhbaIDBhbfbhwhfbaibf
        <div style="width: 100px; text-align: center; background-color: red;">
            <img src="" alt="Nav1" />
            <br />
            <span style="font-size: 80%">Nav1</span>
        </div>
        <div style=" width: 100px; text-align: center;">
            <img src="" alt="Nav2" />
            <br />
            <span style="font-size: 80%">Nav2</span>
        </div>
        <div style=" width: 100px; text-align: center; background-color: red;">
            <img src="" alt="Nav3" />
            <br />
            <span style="font-size: 80%">Nav3</span>
        </div>
</div>
```

No need for `float: left;` CSS.

Comment: Thanks Mohammad,it is working on web page.do you have any idea why it not working when I open the web page from mobile?Thanks.

Comment: Most probably mobile browser doesn't supports `white-space: nowrap;` CSS property.

Comment: do you know what can I change here so it will work on mobile ?

Comment: That would be difficult as I am not aware of your mobile browser capabilities. Anyway I hope your question is answered. If yes, plz mark it answered.

Answer (score 2):

Add `white-space: nowrap` to the #navBar and `display: inline-block;` to the inner divs. I believe that should do it.

Take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fzLwX/1/

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you're looking for:

```
#navBar div{
    overflow-x:auto;
}
```