# How can I get div scroll overflow-x to work on a mobile browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this code that works on desktop browsers. How can I achieve this behaviour on mobile browsers? Basically I want to create a menu which will scroll to the sides.

```
<style type="text/css">
    #navBar {
        height: 55px;
        width: 80px;
        overflow-x: scroll;
        overflow-y:hidden;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }

    #navBar div {
        display: inline-block;
    }
    </style>


    <div id="navBar">
            akdhbaIDBhbfbhwhfbaibf
            <div style="width: 100px; text-align: center; background-color: red;">
                <img src="" alt="Nav1" />
                <br />
                <span style="font-size: 80%">Nav1</span>
            </div>
            <div style=" width: 100px; text-align: center;">
                <img src="" alt="Nav2" />
                <br />
                <span style="font-size: 80%">Nav2</span>
            </div>
            <div style=" width: 100px; text-align: center; background-color: red;">
                <img src="" alt="Nav3" />
                <br />
                <span style="font-size: 80%">Nav3</span>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Didnt you just ask http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11590036/force-inner-elements-to-overflow-x

Comment: yes, i have the answer from mohamad,but I nedd this code to work on mobiles browsers.do you have idea how to make this code work on mobile device ?

Comment: Can you upload your code fully? i work for mobiles i can help you if you can provide more details, and on which devices you are look this is happen?

Comment: Android 2.33 HTC.this is the full code i just put it on page and it works ok on desktop computers but not from mobile.ohhh now i can see in my question some of the css is not in the code section i will fix the question and you will have all the code .Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can enable native scrolling with -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <style>
    div {
      overflow-y: hidden;
      overflow-x: scroll;
      -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
      width: 150px;
      border: 1px solid grey;
    }

    h1 {
      width: 400px;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <h1>some content here</h1>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply,I just put this code in html page and call it from my ipod and from my android htc and it not scrolling.what i am missing?Thanks.

Comment: I have no Android phone to test it today, but I can scroll the div in x direction on my iOS devices with latest firmware. Which versions of iOS/Android do you use?

Comment: wow, this iOS Version is from January 2009! I'm sure you want to upgrade your Firmware.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed! Thank you.